# Cannot parse RSASSA-PSS private key in Go

Tags: go, rsa, x509

I'm trying to parse the RSASSA-PSS key generated with OpenSSL in my project with the following code.

```
privateKeyPath := "private_key.key"
data, err = ioutil.ReadFile(privateKeyPath)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
block, _ := pem.Decode(data)
key, err := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

It fails with the following error message.

```
x509: PKCS#8 wrapping contained private key with unknown algorithm: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10
```

Comment: Possible workaround is to create the key just using the RSA algorithm instead of specifying RSA/PSS. The point is that the keys are specific to RSA, and not to any scheme specified for RSA (be it PKCS#1.5 padding, PSS or even encryption). As such, it is somewhat logical that GoLang will not support the unexpected OID (1.2.840.113549.1.1.10) which indeed specifies RSA/PSS.

Comment: If the key (i.e. the key data itself) is valid and needed, you can also perform the following workaround: Parse the key first with `asn1.Unmarshal()` and then parse the `PrivateKey` property of the result with `x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey()`, s. [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/crypto/x509/pkcs8.go;l=33). This avoids checking the OID and allows the key to be imported successfully.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes sadly, I am restricted to use exactly the PSS key here and I still can't figure out how to parse it properly.